# "relation x does not exist" in Sqlalchemy 2.0 Async when it very clearly does

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I have tried to boil this down to the most basic of test cases. This is part of our test mocking; the db_session is mapped to a test-specific schema, I confirm that the setup works and the test-specific schema has the the required table, and then add a record to that table.

```py
    async def generate(self) -> "Any":
        tables = await self.db_session.execute(text("SELECT table_name FROM test_hero.information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'test_smoke_respond_to_message'"))
        if ("organization",) in tables and self.db_session.get_bind().get_execution_options()["schema_translate_map"]["public"] == "test_smoke_respond_to_message":
            org = SqlOrganization(**self.model_dict)
            async with self.db_session as session:
                session.add(org)
                await session.commit()
                await session.refresh(org)
```

The problem is that `await session.commit()` throws this error:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedTableError'>: relation "organization" does not exist
[SQL: INSERT INTO organization (h_engine_id, natural_language_name, _id) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::UUID) RETURNING organization.created_at, organization.updated_at]
[parameters: ('0fda47a9dfe14d02a6a70e2fd15ddfec', 'Archer Inc', UUID('7b0d6120-6255-4c21-8276-4cd289c7d339'))]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
> /app/app/tests/mock_factory/models.py(51)generate()
```

I am completely out of ideas. How can this possibly execute if the table does *not* exist? How can it possibly fail if the table *does* exist? This is using the same DB connection so there's no possibility of different permissions/scopes.

Here are the related definitions (most of the extraneous methods removed for clarity)

```py
# models.py
class SqlOrganization(NamedBase, TimestampedBase):
    """the highest level of hierarchy in our system."""

    __tablename__ = "organization"
    __pydantic_model__ = "PyOrganization"

    id_prefix = "o"
    engine_id: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(
        String(255), nullable=True, doc="the id of the organization in the Engine"
    )

    platforms: Mapped[List["SqlPlatform"]] = relationship(
        "SqlPlatform", back_populates="organization", lazy="selectin"
    )

# bases.py
class SqlalchemyBase(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    __abstract__ = True
    @property
    def __pydantic_model__(self) -> "str":
        """str representation of the pydantic model"""
        raise NotImplementedError

class NamedBase(SqlalchemyBase):
    __abstract__ = True
    natural_language_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))

# conftest.py
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def test_async_sessionmaker(request):
    function_ = request.node.name
    engine = get_async_engine()
    if "[" in function_:
        function_ = function_.split("[")[0]
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.execute(text('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "vector"'))
        await connection.execute(text(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {function_}"))
        await connection.execute(text(f"SET search_path TO {function_},public"))
        await connection.run_sync(SqlalchemyBase.metadata.drop_all)
        await connection.run_sync(SqlalchemyBase.metadata.create_all)

        await connection.execution_options(schema_translate_map={"public": function_})
    scoped_engine = get_async_engine(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"public": function_}})
    def _test_async_sessionmaker() -> "sessionmaker[AsyncSession]":
        return sessionmaker(bind=scoped_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    return _test_async_sessionmaker
```

Comment: Are you sure the exact table name is `organization`?  The `O` is not capitalized?  Also please show us the definition of `SqlOrganization`.

Comment: 1) didn't you forget to apply migrations \ create tables, 2) are all your models inherited from one instance of `Base`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...[RTFM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_11.html#multi-tenancy-schema-translation-for-table-objects). The secret is in `schema_translate_map`, which functions very differently than I understood it to function. I had this:

```py
scoped_engine = get_async_engine(
    execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"public": function_}}
)
```

Which if you look at this [example from the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#translation-of-schema-names) clearly states that when setting to `{"public": None}`

> Table objects with schema="public" will render with no schema

this is the opposite of what I believed it was doing - I wanted to map objects with no schema (so "public" schema by default) to a schema matching the pytest function name. What I needed to do that was this:

```py
scoped_engine = get_async_engine(
    execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {None: function_}}
)
```

which is very clearly documented in the Sqlalchemy 2.0 docs. It also reads correctly in English: "when the schema is None, use this schema."